# Sources on twisted/local (co)homology

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, poincare-duality

Any suggestions for sources to learn about (co)homology with twisted/local coefficients? I've read Hatcher's [section 3.H](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehatcher/AT/ATch3.4.pdf) and have previously been directed to Sakasai's paper [A Survey of Magnus Representations](https://arxiv.org/abs/1005.5501). Do people have any other favorite sources, especially those with lots of examples, to understand this somewhat mind-twisting topic? Books, notes, papers, recorded lectures, I'll take them all.

To focus things a bit, I should say that I'm a topologist. So I prefer things to be more of a pictorial/geometric nature rather than straight algebra. Also, I'm curious if there is any sort of generalized Poincare duality statement for manifolds with arbitrary coefficient systems. If you know a reference about that, please do share.

Comment: Usually, PD is proven in greater generality, with sheaf coefficients. The proof is the same as the one with constant coefficients. If you want a more direct proof which does not use sheafs, see https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.00569

Comment: Davis & Kirk do it in a few different ways and iirc prove them equivalent. For example, given $X$, then $C_*(\tilde{X})$ is a complex of $\mathbb Z[\pi_1 X]$ modules, which gives one definition, and others come from local systems or locally constant sheaves. I think that all three are handled in [chapter 5](https://jfdmath.sitehost.iu.edu/teaching/m623/book.pdf). Maybe you will find that helpful. [here](https://scholar.harvard.edu/files/rastern/files/1_serre_wyatt.pdf) is a treatment of Serre SS using the local systems algebraic approach.